# (C++) Out of Range Error for Replace Function Inside For Loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, replace

I am running into an 'out of range' error when trying to replace a character at a specific i index inside a for loop. A prompt asks to accept passwords only containing numbers.
For each character in passPhrase that is not a number, replace the character with '0'.
Ex: If the input is 32L04, then the output is:
Adjusted password: 32004
This is what I have so far:

```
string passPhrase;
unsigned int i;

cin >> passPhrase;
for (i = 0; i < passPhrase.size(); ++i) {
    if (!isdigit(passPhrase.at(i))) {
        passPhrase.replace(passPhrase.at(i), 1, "0");
    }
}
cout << "Adjusted password: " << passPhrase << endl;
```

Running this code outputs an out of range error, and I cannot seem to be able to understand why exactly that is.
I did, however, find that changing the line `passPhrase.replace(passPhrase.at(i), 1, "0");` to
`passPhrase.at(i) = '0';` yields the correct outputs. This does make sense to me and is probably the more effective answer, but if anyone can explain why my original line yields an error, that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please take some time to read [a good `replace` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace). What is the first argument supposed to be? What are you passing for the first argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typo:

```
passPhrase.replace(passPhrase.at(i), 1, "0");

// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
// This is a random nubmer between 0 and 255
// or -128 and 127 where a position between 
// 0 and passPhrase.size() - 1 is expected.
```

Should be

```
passPhrase.replace(i, 1, "0");
```

Or just

```
passPhrase[i] = '0';
```